# Como faço para colocar um menu abaixo da logo?

Tags: html, div

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que meu menu apareça no *index*. Como faço para coloca o menu embaixo do logo?

Este é o código:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="left"> 
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="right"></div>

   <id="Logo"><center><h2><b>CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE</b></center></h2>
   <br>

   <div id="center"><a href="menu.html" target="menu.html"></div>
```

Comment: Dê um pouco mais de detalhes, poste seu código... Do jeito que a pergunta está fica difícil podermos ajudar você.

Comment: ele só aparece o logo mais nada do menu embaixo

Comment: Você está usando um `</div>` para fechar uma `<div>` que não foi aberta em lugar nenhum e portanto nem sequer existe. Você está usando uma tag html `<id="Logo">`, mas não existe nenhuma tag HTML chamada `<id>`.

Answer (score 2):

É por que não tem menu nenhum no seu código.

O A HREF serve para linkar uma página no sentido dela ser acessada ao clicar em algo, por exemplo:

```
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com'>Clique aqui para acessar o Stack Overflow em Português</a>
```

O que você procura, caso queira incluir um HTML dentro de outro, é um INCLUDE. E isto depende do servidor.

Veja um exemplo em PHP:

```php
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="left"> 
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="right">
   <div id="Logo"><center><h2><b>CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE</b></center></h2></div>
   <br>
   <div id="center">
<?php include( 'menu.html'); ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Veja um exemplo de SSI do Apache (server side include):

```php
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="left"> 
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="right">
   <div id="Logo"><center><h2><b>CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE</b></center></h2></div>
   <br>
   <div id="center">
<!--#include virtual="/menu.html" -->
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ambas as soluções dependem do servidor estar configurado para isto.

### O IFrame:

Não recomendo, mas uma possibilidade é usar um `<iframe>` para carregar o menu:

```php
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="left"> 
   <img src="img/belo.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="80" align="right">
   <div id="Logo"><center><h2><b>CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE</b></center></h2></div>
   <br>
   <iframe src="menu.html" width=600 height=200></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** Corrigi um DIV ID que estava errado também.

Comment: o id de alguma forma esta bloqueando o script

Comment: @MarcelojavaSilva veja a nota que eu pus no final